# Sort the list based on the top level domain (edu, com, org, in)

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a list,

`url = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]`;

Sort the list based on the top level domain (edu, com, org, in) 
I am very new to python, i tried to solve this by sorting the list by the second last term i.e "d,o,r,i". But the output I get is not as expected could you help me understand why?

---

```
url = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]
def myFn(s):
    return s[-2]

print sorted(url,key=myFn) `
```

---

i get the following output:

```
['www.annauniv.edu', 'www.bis.org.in', 'www.rbi.org.in', 'www.google.com', 'www.ndtv.com', 'www.website.org']
```

---

But when i try with this list `url=["x.ax","u.ax","x.cx","y.cx","y.by"]` i get the corect result i.e

```
['x.ax', 'u.ax', 'y.by', 'x.cx', 'y.cx']
```

Comment: @AshishKumarS For `url = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]`, what should be the expected output? Should it be sorted alphabetically ?

Comment: @taurus05 they should come in this order  first edu then   com then  org the  in

Comment: @AshishKumarS, then i guess it's not alphabetical order.

Comment: @taurus05  if you see in .edu .com .in .org if you sort with d o i and r then it can be alphabetical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s[-2]` means to take the second-from-right character; so for "www.annauniv.edu", that'd be the "d" in ".edu". So you're sorting on the second-last character.

Instead, try:

```
return s.split('.')[-1]
```

`split('.')` will split your input string (e.g., "www.annauniv.edu") into a list split by the '.' character (i.e., ["www", "annauniv", "edu"], and then the `[-1]` will select the first from the right (i.e. "edu")

edit:

Okay, so I see you want to sort in a specific order other than actual collating. In that case you'll need to define that order somehow. Here's one way:

```
def myFn(s):
    preferred_order = ["edu", "com", "org", "in"]
    tld=s.split('.')[-1]
    return preferred_order.index(tld)
```

The `.index()` call returns the position that the string occupies in the list `preferred_order` (that's an arbitrary variable name, you could use `foo` or anything else).

So, `tld=s.split('.')[-1]` sets `tld` to something like "com" or "edu". Then `preferred_order.index(tld)` looks up that `tld` in the list `preferred_order` and returns its position (starting with 0). So for "edu", you'll get a 0; for "org" you'll get a 2, etc. The upshot is that you'll be sorting on the order you listed them in `preferred_order`.

It's going to choke with a `ValueError` if it hits a tld you hadn't thought of though. You can have a default value in that case though:

```
def myFn(s):
    preferred_order = ["edu", "com", "org", "in"]
    tld=s.split('.')[-1]
    try:
        ranking = preferred_order.index(tld)
    except ValueError:
        ranking = 99999 # to sort unknowns at end; use -1 to sort at beginning 
    return ranking
```

Comment: @codingatty, see the comments below the question. This is not what OP expected.

Comment: @codingatty your code works could you tell me what does this line "preferred_order.index(tld)" do

Comment: @AshishKumarS It simply return `0` if tld is `edu`, `1` if tld is `com` and so on.

Comment: Yes, what josephting said; I've edited it to make that a little more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're doing `-2`, so it gets the second-to-last characters, so some stuff ending like `com` would be just `om`, so use:

```
print(sorted(url,key=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1]))
```

Jab's version is this using a function, Kirk's one is using `reversed`, but still, his could use `[::-1]` instead.

**Edit: (thanks to taurus05 for correcting me)**

```
def func(x):
    d = {'edu':'e','com':'m','org':'o'}
    return d.get(x.split('.')[-1],'z')

print(sorted(urls, key=func))
```

Comment: @U9-Forward, see the comments below the question. This is not what OP expected.

Comment: @U9-Forward, it looks like you've been too much used to, using lambda's, that you forgot about the readability of the code. :)

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you probably also want "www.google.com" to come before "www.ndtv.com", and "web3.example.com" to come before "www.example.com", right? Here's how you can do that:

```
urls = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]

def key_function(s):
    # Turn "www.google.com" into ["www", "google", "com"], then
    # reverse it to ["com", "google", "www"].
    return list(reversed(s.split('.')))

# Now this will sort ".com" before ".edu", "google.com" before "ndtv.com",
# and so on.
print(sorted(urls, key=key_function))
```

Comment: Or `s.split('.')[::-1]`, which may be a bit easier. Anyway, +1 for taking the other parts of the URL into account.

Comment: Acording to the question "Sort the list based on the top level domain (edu, com, org, in)" so i need to have .edu  in first place .com secon and so on

Comment: @KirkStrauser,  see the comments below the question. This is not what OP expected.

Comment: @taurus05 Then I have no idea what's actually expected and I give up. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the last part of the strings after a period. Use this as your function.

```
url = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]
def myFn(s):
    return s.split('.')[-1]

print sorted(url,key=myFn)
```

**Edit**

Since your requirements are more complex than a simple alphanumeric sorting, then the below function seems like a logical solution.

```
def myFunc(s, order=('edu','com','in','org')):
    try: return order.index(s.split('.')[-1])
    except ValueError: return len(order)
```

Comment: @Jab, see the comments below the question. This is not what OP expected.

Comment: My apologies, I was at work. I edited. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers, work as you were expecting. This will work excatly as intended. For clarification, read comments below the question.

```
urls = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]

def func(x):
  x = x.split('.')[-1]
  print(x)
  if x == 'edu':
    return 'e'
  elif x == 'com':
    return 'm'
  elif x == 'org':
    return 'o'
  else:
    return 'z'

print(sorted(urls, key=func))
```

Output: Order -> [edu, com, org, in]

```
['www.annauniv.edu', 'www.google.com', 'www.ndtv.com', 'www.website.org', 'www.bis.org.in', 'www.rbi.org.in']
```

**Update**:
I am returning alphabets in order to maintain the required order.

Comment: you changed your previous answer? This will work and this is quite easy to understand thanks.

Comment: @AshishKumarS, you can upvote it so that it can be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to take the whole top level domain, and not just the second to last character. Imagine a case where you had two top levels like "edu" and "add". These two would not be guaranteed to sort correctly because the "edu" may end up before the "add". So here's a solution:

```
url = ['www.annauniv.edu', 'www.google.com', 'www.ndtv.com', 'www.website.org', 'www.bis.org.in', 'www.rbi.org.in']

def topLevelDomain(domain: str):
    # Split from the right, max of one split.
    # This only takes the right hand side after the last period in the string.
    return domain.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]

print(sorted(url, key=topLevelDomain))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because not all TLDs always have 2 characters. With many more expanded TLDs released nowadays, there are a lot more longer TLDs out there.

Instead of `s[-2]`, you can use `s.split('.')[-1]` instead.

1. Split string with `.` into arrays: `s.split('.')`

   ```
   www.bis.org.in
   > ['www', 'bis', 'org', 'in']
   ```
2. Get the last element: `[-1]`

   ```
   > 'in'
   ```

On top of that, you can specify a dict to sort based on that first before falling back to alphabetical order.

```
url = ["www.annauniv.edu", "www.abc.co.uk", "x.dev", "x.mom", "www.google.com", "www.ndtv.com", "www.website.org", "www.bis.org.in", "www.rbi.org.in"]

def myFn(x):
    order = {'edu': 0, 'com': 1, 'org': 2, 'in': 3}
    tld = x.split('.')[-1]
    return order[tld] if tld in order.keys() else tld

print(sorted(url, key=myFn))
```

will return

```
['www.annauniv.edu',
 'www.google.com',
 'www.ndtv.com',
 'www.website.org',
 'www.bis.org.in',
 'www.rbi.org.in',
 'x.dev',
 'x.mom',
 'www.abc.co.uk']
```

What's happening behind the scene is number will get sorted in front of string of characters.

If TLDs are either edu, com, org or in, it will be sorted with their respective number.

Everything else will be sorted alphabetically with the TLD itself.

Comment: see the comments below the question. This is not what OP expected.

Comment: @taurus05 Thanks for the note. I didn't read the question thoroughly.